# Git diff for n'th modified file?

Tags: git

Suppose we change several files, and want to view the diff for one at a time, I know we can use something like this

```sh
git status

Changes not staged for commit:
 directory)
    modified:   app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss
    modified:   app/javascript/packs/application.js
    modified:   app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
    modified:   config/webpack/environment.js
```

and run

```sh
git diff app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss
```

then

```sh
git diff app/javascript/packs/application.js
```

and so on..

```sh
git diff app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
```

To view each of the files' diffs one by one (one by one is desired here, but all the typing of file paths isn't, even with tab to auto complete).

#### Question

Is there a way to achieve the same (i.e. view git diff for a single file at a time) but without having to type (manually, nor with tab autocomplete) the full path to the changed file? (e.g. can we reference somehow, pseudo-code: `git diff --mod_file 1`, `git diff --mod_file 2` etc) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're working in a bash-like shell, you can define a shell function such as

```sh
function gitdiffn() {
    git diff ${@:2} $(git diff --name-only | sed -n "$1 p") 
}
```

which can then be used to browse the list of modified files (with 1-based indexing)
as

```sh
$ gitdiffn 1
$ gitdiffn 2
# ...
```

By including `${@:2}` before the `$(command substitution)` that fetches the nth file name, we allow for the propagation additional arbitrary flags to the `git diff` invocation, so commands like

```sh
$ gitdiffn 1 --minimal
```

will work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the search capability of `less`. That is, you type

```
git diff
```

as always, then type `/^diff` to search for the hunk headers, then type `n` until you arrive at the file you are interested in. Type `N` to search backwards.

`less` remembers recently used search patterns. Next time around it suffices to type `n`. Use up- and down-arrows to cycle through recently used patterns.

Answer (score 1):

I think `git difftool` will do what you want.

Perhaps you want to install some own difftool, whatever suits your needs.